# How can we store the csrf cookies at user’s browser side?

Tags: angular, csrf

I have a backend api call which it need the csrf cookies so may I know from user’s browser how can I enable this and during post or get it able to have this csrf cookies?
I am using Angular as my frontend.

Comment: Pleas read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You'll need to add an http interceptor in order to set the `withCredentials` option to true, which will pass cookies for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.